# SVN: Get specific files from specific revision

Tags: svn

I want to check out a specific revision from my SVN, but only the files that have been commited in that revision.
I could check out the whole revision, export the files and then delete anything that is not listed in the revision history, but it would be far less time consuming if I could just check out the files I need.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you'll need to use a couple of commands to do this.

First take the files that were changed as part of that commit (if you want to make a script with this, you might want to also use the parameter `--xml` as it might be easier to get the data, rather than parsing the text)

```
svn log -r [revision] -v
```

and then for each file run an export

```
svn export -r [revision] [file_url]
```